# bootstrap selectpicker works slow

Tags: ajax, twitter-bootstrap, browser, drop-down-menu

Why do ajax load of boot bootstrap selectpicker works slow in browser mostly in IE browser.

I have written ajax code which render page having more than 100 selectpicker. but the code works too slow on Firefox and Chrome browser. works too much slow in IE11 browser.

any solution to speedup the process